# how to let updatemany validate mongoose schema on every modified document ?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, schema, this

I 've got an issue with mongoose schema validation, while trying to validate the schema of documents modified inside a Model::updateMany (or update + mutli:true) request. 
I've got the schema below:

```
  var BusinessesSchema = new Schema({
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    openingDate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    },
    endingDate: {
      type: Date,
      validate: function(value) {
        if (this.constructor.name === 'Query') {
          // Looks like this is a validation for update request
          var doc = null;
          switch (this.op) {
            case 'update':
            case 'updateMany': {
              doc = this._update.$set;
              break;
            }
            case 'findOneAndUpdate': {
              doc = this._update;
              break;
            }
            default:
            // keep null, will throw an error
          }
          return doc.openingDate < value;
        }
        else {
          return this.openingDate < value;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I would like to access modified documents value ("this") inside endingDate::validate function to make sure that for each modified document ending Date is greater than beginning one .

Even, when using pre-hook (for update & updateMany, as below), I still do not find any way to access the modified documents value to perform my check when multi is set (or when calling updateMany).

```
BusinessesSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  this.options.runValidators = true;
  this.options.context = 'query';
  next();
});

BusinessesSchema.pre('updateMany', function(next) {
  this.options.runValidators = true;
  this.options.context = 'query';
  next();
});
```

I probably missed something, and would really appreciate help here.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that. Best you can do with `updateMany` is to capture the query context, from `this`, and analyze the update. Something like this:

```
Schema.pre('updateMany', function (next) {
    const update = this.getUpdate();
    if (update.$set && update.$set && !validateUpdate(update.$set)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Update');
    }
    next();
});
```

If you wanna do validation on the resulting document before the update using the `save` hook, you can use a cursor:

```
Schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!validDoc(this)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid Doc');
    }
    next();
}
Schema.statics.updateManyWithValidation = async function(criteria, update) {
        const cursor = Model.find(criteria).cursor();
        let doc = null;
        do {
            doc = await cursor.next();
            Object.assign(doc, update);
            await doc.save();
         } while(doc != null);
    }
```

Now, bear in mind this is a much more expensive operation since you're fetching the documents, applying the changes, and then saving them individually.